# java program to get ip isp information

Tags: java

I use java program to get the ip addresses from log file, then i need get the ISP of ip and 
the organization of ip. I use

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/"+ip);
```

to get the html content and then get the ISP information from the html content,
but this website can only free use 20 times per day, so can you give me someother methods to get the ISP information.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36817/who-provides-a-whois-api

Answer (score 1):

```
request.getHostAddress();
```

this will give the ip address